# USB Headset Prevents Media Playing on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa, pipewire, usb-audio

I recently bought a USB headset and it has been behaving very inconsistently. Sometimes it works fine but other times, if I try to play any media, it acts as if it is buffering until I unplug the headset.

Running `speaker-test` (both with and without `-c2`) either hangs or produces the error `Write error: -77,File descriptor in bad state`. The latter I haven't been able to reproduce since installing `sof-firmware`, but this hasn't helped in any other way.

My headset is EPOS H3 Hybrid and my laptop is a Dell G15 Ryzen Edition.

For my audio, I use PireWire with Wireplumber, as compatibility, pipewire-pulse, pipewire-alsa, and pipewire-jack.

Whenever I play audio, `journalctl` seems to fill with `spa.alsa: front:3: (250 missed) snd_pcm_avail after recover: Broken pipe`.

Additionally, my laptop speakers don't seem to work at the moment but media will still play.

Does anyone know how this could be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have conflicting bitrates for different devices, or a quanta (latency) issue causing x-runs, etc. Don't know that this will solve your issue but worth a shot.

To force everything to 48000 bitrate:

```
pw-metadata -n settings 0 clock.force-rate 48000
```

To force everything to 500 sample quanta:

```
pw-metadata -n settings 0 clock.force-quantum 500
```

You can run these both replacing 48000 and 500 with 0 to reset to default values.

I also recommend installing qpwgraph so you can see what is connected to where, etc.

Comment: You are a lifesaver; I remember looking for a solution for this for ages, finally finding one, then it breaking again today, but I've never seen this anywhere until now and it worked perfectly, so thank you so much

Comment: glad it helped you!